# XPages - show image contained with email in xpage document

Tags: image, email, xpages

I am working on an internal helpdesk. Emails address to the helpdesk appear in a Notes View, and I can open the document in XPages and see the text. But it won't show any inserted images within the text.

I can list the attachments as external links (courtesy of http://techdriveactive.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/open-attachments-in-xpage-in-client.html) but I can't seem to get a handle on the images.

Any ideas ??

Comment: have a look at the source code. Does it show the href tags? Where do they point? Eventually some onLoad() JS can fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way around that challenge is to use a Dojo [ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html). It has a href attribute that can point to a different url. You then can point it to the content rendered by the classic engine:

```
      href="someview/docid/Body?OpenField"
```

Note: this won't work in XPiNC

Comment: Wow, so simple when you know how. Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

To you HelpDeskOpenDoc.xsp XPage add a Rich Text control and bind it to the Rich Text Field with the images and other rich content ...

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" value="#{document1.Body}"></xp:inputRichText>
```